# Python multiprocessing restarting the application

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, executable

I am a newbie in python multiprocessing, and came across some behaviour which looks strange to me but I guess it is normal. Here is a minimal working code:

```
import multiprocessing

print("Thread name: " + __name__)

def printfunc(text):
    print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    texts=["aaa","bbb"]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    result = pool.map(printfunc, texts)

    pool.close()
```

the output I get from running this is:

```
Thread name: __main__
Thread name: __parents_main__
Thread name: __parents_main__
aaa
bbb
```

evidently the multiprocessing thread executes not only the `printfunc` function but the whole code from the start. And apparently the way to distinguish between the main thread and the "children"-threads is `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition; main thread's name is `__main__` and childrens' names are `__parents_main__`. However for my work I need to freeze my code and create Windows executable, and when I run it, all the threads have the name `__main__` and this creates problems.

Are there ways to:

a) Make it so that the application is not "restarted" after calling `Pool.map` ?

b) If it's impossible, how to properly freeze the application so threads have different names (I use cx_Freeze) ?

c) If this is also impossible, how this behaviour could be prevented in any other way ?

I use python 2.7.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, because `Pool.map` imports the module containing the function you pass in. You should basically use the `Process` class directly. Also see [the multiprocessing guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming): `Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried using `Process` instead of `Pool.map` on the above code, but got the same issue that the main module was restarted for both of the threads.